# Access JSON array inside another array

Tags: ios, swift

So far I only had to deal with simple JSON arrays with only a single array. I have now combined 2 arrays together so I can get my user data and all the reviews for that user:

```
[
{
    "user_id": "16",
    "name": "Jonh",
    "lastName": "appleseed",
    "username": "jonh@me.com",
    "sex": "male",
    "image_url": "",
    "review": [
        {
            "reviewID": "4",
            "merchant_id": "17",
            "rating": "5",
            "user_id": "16",
            "comments": "Very good customer. Strongly suggested",
            "date": "0000-00-00",
            "reviewYear": "",
            "publish": "1"
        },
        {
            "reviewID": "8",
            "merchant_id": "16",
            "rating": "2",
            "user_id": "16",
            "comments": "Automatic review due to "NO SHOW" without informing the merchant",
            "date": "0000-00-00",
            "reviewYear": "",
            "publish": "1"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

before I added the reviews my model looked like this:

```
import Foundation

class Users {
    let userImage:String?
    let name:String?
    let sex:String?
    let image_url:String?

    init(dictionary:NSDictionary) {            
        userImage = dictionary["userImage"]    as? String
        name = dictionary["name"]    as? String
        sex = dictionary["sex"]    as? String
        image_url = dictionary["image_url"]    as? String
    }
}

func loadUser(completion:(([Users])-> Void), userId: String){
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.myWebSite.com/api/v1.0/users.php")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "user_id=\(userId)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
        { data, response, error in        
            if error != nil {        
                print("error\(error)")    
            } else {
                do {     
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSArray
                    print(json)

                    var users = [Users]()    
                    for user in json{                            
                        let user = Users(dictionary: user as! NSDictionary)    
                        users.append(user)    
                        let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0 )){
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){        
                                    completion(users)
                            }
                        }    
                    }        
                } catch{   
                }
            }
        }
    task.resume()
}
```

which I could then used in my viewController:

```
func loadModel() {
    let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    loadingNotification.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.Indeterminate
    loadingNotification.labelText = "updating your deals..."
    users = [Users]()
    let api = Api()
    api.loadUser(didLoadUsers , userId: "16")    
}

func didLoadUsers(users:[Users]){        
    self.users = users
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
}
```

Can I get the `review` field so I can present it in a table view controller?

Comment: You should be able to get the "review" object the same was you are getting the strings, except it will be an array of dictionaries (not a string).  Loop through the "review" array and do whatever you want with the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. It was easier than what I thought. I just had to add a `UserReview` class and  change the signature of `loadUser` function:

```
 func loadUser(completion:((user: [Users], review: [UserReview])-> Void), userId: String){

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.myWebsite.com/api/v1.0/users.php")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "user_id=\(userId)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
        { data, response, error in

            if error != nil {

                print("error\(error)")

            }else{

                do{
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSArray

                    var users = [Users]()


                    for user in json{

                        let user = Users(dictionary: user as! NSDictionary as! [String : AnyObject])

                        users.append(user)

        //*********** now I can access the reviews from my son***************
                     let reviewArray = json[0]["review"] as! NSArray
                        var reviews = [UserReview]()


                        for review in reviewArray{

                            let review = UserReview(dictionary: review as! NSDictionary as! [String : AnyObject])

                            reviews.append(review)

                        }

                        let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0 )){

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

                                completion(user: users, review: reviews)
                            }
                        }

                    }

                } catch{

                }
            }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

So I can use it in my tableViewController

```
     var users: [Users]?
     var reviews: [UserReview]?

    func loadModel() {
    let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    loadingNotification.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.Indeterminate
    loadingNotification.labelText = "updating..."
    users = [Users]()
    reviews = [UserReview]()
    let api = Api()
    api.loadUser(didLoadUsers , userId: "16")
}

func didLoadUsers(users:[Users], reviews:[UserReview] ){

        self.users = users
        self.reviews = reviews
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)    

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {

        return users!.count

    }
    if section == 1 {   

        return 1  

    }
    if section == 2 {

    return reviews!.count
    }
    return 0
}
```

So in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I can now load all the reviews

```
if indexPath.section == 2 {

        let review = reviews![indexPath.row]


        let reviewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reviewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserReviewsTableViewCell
        reviewCell.useReview(review)

        return reviewCell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I added to your `Users` class an array of reviews that will be populated in your user `init()` method. I recommend you to take look at `struct Review` and make your user class a struct, and change your `NSDictionary` to  swift `Dictionary`.

```
   struct Review {
    let reviewID:String?
    let merchant_id:String?
    let user_id:String?
    //to be continued with your own implementation...

    init(dictionary:[String:String]) {
        reviewID = dictionary["reviewID"]
        merchant_id = dictionary["merchant_id"]
        user_id = dictionary["user_id"]
        //to be continued with your own implementation...
    }
}
class Users {

    let userImage:String?
    let name:String?
    let sex:String?
    let image_url:String?
    var reviews:[Review]

    init(dictionary:[String:AnyObject]) {

        userImage = dictionary["userImage"]    as? String
        name = dictionary["name"]    as? String
        sex = dictionary["sex"]    as? String
        image_url = dictionary["image_url"]    as? String
        reviews = [Review]()
        if let userReviews = dictionary["review"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
            for review  in userReviews {

                if let unwrapedReview = review as? [String:String] {
                    let r = Review(dictionary: unwrapedReview)
                    reviews.append(r)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also I recommend you in the future to use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) for parsing JSON and also [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for networking requests.

Comment: how can I get the values into the` reviews` array then?

Comment: if I print(user.reviews) I get `myApp.Review(reviewID: Optional("8"), merchant_id: Optional("16"), user_id: Optional("16"))]
()`

Comment: `for review in user.reviews { print(review) }`

Comment: thanks but I had to change my `loadUser` method and I created the `UserReview` class. Now I can load the reviews and users in my `tableViewController`